# Count number of weeks in between days in SQL server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am here again for some help. This is what I am trying to do. I have a function or sp that takes 3 parameters. `startdate, enddate,` and `dayofweek` (m, t, w, etc), need to count how many weeks are in between the start and end date.

Example, if I pass `startday=2011-05-02`,  `enddate=2011-05-10`, and `dayofweek` as Tuesday, it should count 2, if I pass `dayofweek` as wednesday then it should count 1.

I am able to work using this code, is there any better way to do this? The `ClosingStartDate` is being adjusted to the correct start date based on the `dayofweek` used. So basically, the code is adding 1 week to the `runningdate` and running date is adjusted according to the week is used.

Any other way to do it without the  while..loop.???

```
declare @NoofPeriods int
declare @runningdate datetime

 set @runningdate = @ClosingStartDate
 set @NoofPeriods=0
 while (@runningdate <= @NextStatementClosingdate)
  begin
    set @NoofPeriods=@NoofPeriods+1
    set @runningdate = Dateadd(day,7,@runningdate)
  end
```

Comment: ou post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: A question on the requirement... if startday=2011-05-02 (a Monday), enddate=2011-05-09 (the next Monday), and weekday=Monday... should the answer be 2, or 1?

Answer (score 5):

It is already built in to SQL 2005.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(week, @startdate, @enddate)
```

Comment: Works - but doesn't take into account that odd requirement about the "day of week" ....

Comment: And unfortunately `SET DATEFIRST` doesn't apply to `DATEDIFF` - way to go Microsoft! :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm probably not dead on with the SQL Server syntax, but logic like this should work.  Basically use modulo-7 arithmetic to determine how many "odd" days you have at the start of the period, and whether these include one of your chosen weekdays (as determined by your `dayofweek`) or not.

```
@diffInDays = SELECT DATEDIFF(day, @startdate, @enddate)

@startDateDay = SELECT DATEPART(weekday, @startdate)

set @diffInWholeWeeks = @diffInDays / 7
set @diffRemainderDays = @diffInDays % 7

if @diffRemainderDays >= ( ( @dayofweek - @startDateDay ) % 7 )
  begin
    set @extraWeek = 1
  end
else
  begin
    set @extraWeek = 0
  end

set @answer = @diffInWholeWeeks + @extraWeek
```

Answer (score 1):

@slothrop's answer is almost dead on, so I am going to base this on that code and upvote that answer.

Okay this comment was wrong (please ignore):

---

*Because days are from 1-7 instead of 0-6, we need to account for it. I do this by subtracting one after our second modulous. I haven't tested all scenarios, but it seems to work.*

---

What was messing me up was the shift of the week. Add 7 to the dayofweek to make sure the mod works.

This should work,

```
--Setup
DECLARE @dayofweek int = 4
DECLARE @startdate datetime = '5/2/2011'
DECLARE @enddate datetime = '5/10/2011'

--Solution
DECLARE @diffInDays int = DATEDIFF(day, @startdate, @enddate);
DECLARE @startDateDay int = DATEPART(weekday, @startdate);
DECLARE @extraWeek int = 0;

DECLARE @diffInWholeWeeks int = @diffInDays / 7
DECLARE @diffRemainderDays int = @diffInDays % 7

if @diffRemainderDays >= ( ( @dayofweek + 7 - @startDateDay ) % 7 )
    set @extraWeek = 1

DECLARE @answer int = @diffInWholeWeeks + @extraWeek

SELECT @answer
```

Note: I'm not sure the inline setting of declarations is supported in 2005. If so, just use a SET or SELECT statement to set the values.

Comment: I think we can be agnostic to whether days are 1-7 or 0-6 - as long as @dayofweek and @startDateDay are consistent in the convention they use, then the subtraction and modulo takes care of it.  The difference between your code (with the -1) and mine (without) is how we handle the case when the start or end day lies on the weekday itself.  In my code, startdate=2-May-2011, enddate=10-May-2011 and dayofweek=3 (Tue) should give an answer of 2 as the questioner requests.  startdate=2-May-2011, enddate=9-May-11 and dayofweek=2 (Mon) would also give 2.  That seems slightly nonintuitive to me...

Comment: ...but on the other hand is more consistent with the example in the question.  It boils down to whether the date range is to be considered as an inclusive or exclusive interval really.

Comment: yes, you are right slothrop, sometimes I should not answer things quickly. I tend to miss things. I probably edited this 5 times before I got it right.

Comment: No worries - I have the same vice!